# What are the executable files for Android platform?

Tags: android

According to the new security policity on Android Play, an app can not download itself executable files from the cloud.

https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/malicious-behavior/

To check it, I need to know all the file extensions that can contain an executable file for Android. But I can not find any complete list. So, could anyone help?

I've found these extensions so far.

> jar, aar, apk, so, dex..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing about downloading apk's. And why should it?

Comment: Well, I guess is an executable file, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. But the document talks about files containing executable code. Not about executable files.